# How to combine multiple RegEx commands for Notepad++ using capture groups and alternations?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I am converting exported SQL views as files to a different syntax using a separate specialized conversion tool. This tool can't handle certain commands and formatting so I'm using Notepad++ with RegEx to alter the files ahead of time.

So far I am getting the results that I want, but it takes three separate Find/Replace actions. **I'd like to reduce these three RegEx actions down to one if possible.**

````
Find: (.*)(CREATE VIEW.*\nGO)(.*)
Replace: \2

Find: (CREATE VIEW )(.*)(\r\nAS)
Replace: \1"\2"\3

Find: (oldschema1\.|\[oldschema1\]\.|\[|\]|TOP \(100\) PERCENT|oldschema2\.)|(^GO$)|(\A^(.*?))
Replace: (?1)(?2\;)(?3SET SCHEMA schemaname\; \n\n\1)```
````

I'm using Notepad++ 7.7.1 64-bit, Find/Replace with Regular Expression search mode - ". matches newline" check on.

You'll see in my code that I'm already using capture groups with alternation. I thought I could combine the first two RegEx steps as additional capture groups to Step 3 but it doesn't work out, possibly because they are nested.

I tried referencing the nested groups by incrementing the referencing number accordingly, but it doesn't work (blanks out the result).

Here is an example SQL view file. It's not a working view because I added "oldschema2" so the RegEx would have something to find for one of the replacements, but it's representative as an example here.

```
garbage 
text 
beforehand

CREATE VIEW [oldschema1].[viewname]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         TOP (100) PERCENT oldschema1.TABLENAME.FIELD1, oldschema1.TABLENAME.FIELD2
FROM            oldschema1.TABLENAME
WHERE        (oldschema1.TABLENAME.FIELD3 = N'Z003') AND oldschema2.TABLENAME.FIELD2 = 1
ORDER BY oldschema1.TABLENAME.FIELD1

GO

garbage 
text
after
```

Here is some additional details of what I'm trying to achieve with each pass.

Notepad++ RegEx Step 1 - isolate view block from CREATE VIEW to GO

Find: 
`(.*)(CREATE VIEW.*\nGO)(.*)`

Replace: 
`\2`

Step 2 - put quotes around view name

Find: 
`(CREATE VIEW )(.*)(\r\nAS)`

Replace: 
`\1"\2"\3`

Step 3 - remove/replace various texts and insert a line at the beginning of the file

Find: 
`(oldschema1\.|\[oldschema1\]\.|\[|\]|TOP \(100\) PERCENT|oldschema2\.)|(^GO$)|(\A^(.*?))`

Replace: 
`(?1)(?2\;)(?3SET SCHEMA schemaname\; \n\n\1)`

The expected output from the above example would be:

```
SET SCHEMA schemaname;

CREATE VIEW "viewname"
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         TABLENAME.FIELD1, TABLENAME.FIELD2
FROM            TABLENAME
WHERE        (TABLENAME.FIELD3 = N'Z003') AND TABLENAME.FIELD2 = 1
ORDER BY TABLENAME.FIELD1

;
```

which I achieve with the above three steps, but I'd like to do it in one Find/Replace if possible.

I'm pretty new to RegEx, and StackOverflow for that matter. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A single regex will be too complex. I suggest you to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score -1):

#### Step 1

I'm not so sure about it, but I'm guessing that maybe we would want an expression similar to:

```
[\s\S]*?(CREATE VIEW[\s\S]*GO\s*)[\s\S]*
```

to be replaced with `$1`, where our desired data is in this capturing group:

```
(CREATE VIEW[\s\S]*GO\s*)
```

and we can even remove `\s*`:

```
(CREATE VIEW[\s\S]*GO)
```

and just try:

```
[\s\S]*?(CREATE VIEW[\s\S]*GO)[\s\S]*
```

with an `m` flag.

In the right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4ZUij/1/), the expression is further explained, if you might be interested.

#### Step 2

We can likely try:

```
(CREATE VIEW)(.*)
```

and replace with:

```
SET SCHEMA schemaname;\n\n$1 "viewname"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/03AQ1L/1/)

#### Step 3

This step would probably be done with an expression similar to:

```
TOP \(100\) PERCENT |oldschema1\.
```

being replaced with an empty string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/03AQ1L/1/)

#### Step 4:

`\s*GO` being replaced with `\n;` or just `;` and we might likely have the desired output, not sure though.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5a8JBx/1/)